# How can I use templates in Angular UI bootstrap dialogs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using the [Angular UI bootstrap module](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dialog) for opening a dialog.

There is a option for mentioning the path of template like

```
$scope.opts = {
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true,
            backdropClick: true,
            template: '<p>Template</p>',
            controller: 'TestDialogController'
          }
```

my app is in  `site/app`  then `js , partials`

I am not able to find how it finds templates

Comment: What's your question? What does _"my app is in site/app then js , partials"_ mean?

Comment: i mean the all the angular app is inside that folder. that was the folder structure

Comment: Show us the layout of your project (html, js, anything relevant...).  I would think you should remove the first '/' in your template and use something like `template: 'partials/test.html'` instead, but it boils down to where the template is relative to the html page itself.

Answer (score 6):

The Angular UI bootstrap dialog takes either a template inline,

```
template: '<p>This is a inline template</p>';
```

or the template url can be specified as both a relative and absolute path.

```
templateUrl: '/relative/path/dialog.html';
```

*Try to open a browser tab pointing to your template first, and when you successfully have derived the path you can try to add it to your templateUrl.*

You can read more about correct usage of the directive [here](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/#/dialog).

Answer (score 1):

There's a use of `<script>` as a directive which would allow you to make a hybrid approach.

Angular docs mention that if you use a declaration in your html like:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
  Content of the template.
</script>
```

Then you can use it as a reference in a directive such as `ngInclude` or `ngView`, and even a service like `$route`. You can see this working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnwun/wW58G/).

Comment: Not sure why -1. I'm talking about angularjs [template cache system](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache), which allows a template not to be real html file served by a server, but a portion of html code within your html.

Comment: Yeah the question is specific to Angular UI Bootstrap and the overriding of these templates.